# Run only one instance of node task

Tags: node.js, express, cron

**Description:** 
I have node module that parses external monitoring pages and pushes daily data to db. This task can take about 10min and is scheduled to run once per day via node-cron. I have also page where you can start this task manually with extra arguments (like id or date). This is accessed by express route (lets say `app.post('/manual-task', runTask)`). Cron job and http route is part of express restfull api app.

**Question:** 
I want only one running instance of this module (its actually class module) , f.e. somebody starts this task on page, but there is already running cron job for this task. It should alert user that job is already in progress. I have some ideas, but I would like to avoid bad practicies:

- pid?
- environmental variable?
- cron job as request to api instead of direct execution?
- should I use child process if I run it inside express route?

What is the best way and practice how to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Why does it matter if it runs more than once? Just curious, but it might also inform what the best answer is

Comment: @Paul that external monitoring pages are really old and slow. Some requests take up to 1min so two or more simultaneously running parsers make it only worse. And imagine double click or even more clicks. I want limit this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need a persistent way for multiple instances of your process to share state. If possible, the best approach would be system-independent (ie not something on the machine running, like `pid` or env variable) so your solution could scale to multiple machines, for deploying the API separately from the cron job.

There are a few approaches depending on your requirements but they all revolve around your process:

- doing a check when it first starts up to see if another process is
  running.

  - if one is, potentially quit? Logic is up to you.
  - otherwise, the current process needs to record it has started.
- do the parsing.
- record that it has stopped when it is finished parsing.

The best approach to do this would be to have each process acquire a [`Lock`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) when it is started, perhaps using [Redis as a lock](https://redis.io/topics/distlock). There's even a [library for node](https://github.com/mike-marcacci/node-redlock).

If you're not too worried about a [Race Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), you don't have to implement the locking system. I'd still recommend something like Redis to store when a process is running, but you could also just write to a file or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for tips. Is mysql suitable alternative to Redis? If I understand your suggestion, its "one record" table. And performance is not important for such purpose. This app uses Mysql so I can reuse it..

Comment: Probably, I've found this library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-semaphore). Though not a great package, it seems like it is possible with MySQL.